# How to get list of all leaf folders from ADLS Gen2 path via Scala code?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

We have folders and subfolders in it with year,month, day folders in it. How can we get only the last leaf level folder list using dbutils.fs.ls utility?

Example path:

abfss://cont@storage.dfs.core.windows.net/customer/data/V1/2021/
abfss://cont@storage.dfs.core.windows.net/customer/data/V1/2022/
abfss://cont@storage.dfs.core.windows.net/customer/data/V1/2022/03/24/15/a.parquet
abfss://cont@storage.dfs.core.windows.net/customer/data/V1/2022/03/25/15/b.parquet
.
.

The function should return only last leaf level folder list i.e

abfss://cont@storage.dfs.core.windows.net/customer/data/V1/2022/03/24/15
abfss://cont@storage.dfs.core.windows.net/customer/data/V1/2022/03/25/15

EDIT:

I have tried below function and it works but it fails when some folder is empty with error "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.reduceLeft". Please help.

```
def listLeafDirectories(path: String): Array[String] =
  dbutils.fs.ls(path).map(file => {
    // Work around double encoding bug
    val path = file.path.replace("%25", "%").replace("%25", "%")
    if (file.isDir) listLeafDirectories(path)
    else Array[String](path.substring(0,path.lastIndexOf("/")+1))
  }).reduce(_ ++ _).distinct
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below function worked for me

```
 def listDirectories(dir: String, recurse: Boolean): Array[String] = {
    dbutils.fs.ls(dir).map(file => {
      val path = file.path.replace("%25", "%").replace("%25", "%")
      if (file.isDir) listDirectories(path,recurse)
      else Array[String](path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/")+1))
    }).reduceOption(_ union _).getOrElse(Array()).distinct
  }
```

Comment: This function does not use the recurse parameter.  What is that supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

> The function should return only last leaf level folder list

You can use fold function of scala.

```
def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1
```

Folds the elements of this list using the specified associative binary operator. The default implementation in IterableOnce is equivalent to foldLeft but may be overridden for more efficient traversal orders.

The order in which operations are performed on elements is unspecified and may be nondeterministic.

**returns**
the result of applying the fold operator op between all the elements and z, or z if this list is empty.

For more information refer this [link](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#fold%5BA1%3E:A%5D(z:A1)(op:(A1,A1)=%3EA1):A1)